# action.type undefined in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an error with redux: action.type is undefined. I've narrowed it down to one of my actions:

```
export function LOAD_PRODUCTS() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products')
    .then((res) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({type: 'PRODUCTS_LOADED', payload: res})
        }
    }) 
    .catch((err) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({type: "PRODUCTS_ERROR", payload: err})
        }
    })
}
```

or maybe the Reducer...

```
export function reducer(
    state = {
        fbkey: '',
        userSuccess: null,
        cart: [],
        nav: null,
        tab: true,
        error: {}, 
        loading: false,
        products: []
    }, action) {


    switch (action.type) {
          case "FBTOKEN": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fbkey: action.payload
            }
          }

        case "NAV_OPEN" : {
            return {
                ...state, 
                nav: true
            }
        }

        case "NAV_CLOSE" : {
            return {
                ...state,
                nav: false
            }
        }

        case "USER_SUCCESS" : {
            return {
                ...state, 
                userSuccess: true
            }
        }

        case "USER_ERROR" : {
            return { 
                ...state,
                userSuccess: false
            }
        }

        case "ADD_TO_CART" : {
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: action.payload
            }
        }
        case "TAB_CLOSE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                tab: action.payload
            }
        }

        case "TAB_OPEN": {
            return {
                ...state, 
                tab: action.payload
            }
        }

        case "PRODUCTS_LOADED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload
            }
        }

        case "PRODUCTS_ERROR": {
            return {
                ...state, 
                error: action.payload
            }
        }

        case "IS_LOADING": {
            return {
                ...state, 
                loading: action.payload
            }
        }

        case "IS_NOT_LOADING": {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: action.payload
            }
        }

        default: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, somehow the type isn't being returned properly. How can I fix that?

EDIT: Thunk is being used here. I also added the reducer code.. Returning the dispatch function doesn't work either. Maybe it has something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return dispatch try below code

```
export function LOAD_PRODUCTS() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products')
    .then((res) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            return dispatch({type: 'PRODUCTS_LOADED', payload: res})
        }
    }) 
    .catch((err) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            return dispatch({type: "PRODUCTS_ERROR", payload: err})
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I did that. Thank you.

Comment: Just for shake of curiosity, what was the issue ? And also did it worked without returning dispatcher ??

Comment: No it didn't work. The issue is action.type is undefined in that place. `export default function routerMiddleware(history) {
  return function () {
    return function (next) {
      return function (action) {
        if (action.type !== CALL_HISTORY_METHOD) {
          return next(action);
        }
`

Comment: If you were curious to the answer reddit got it done https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/75pl6n/actiontype_undefined/